# Make canvas line show

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Ok, here is something simple, I hope. I've a div container in which I can click and what I'm trying to do is to create two perpendicular lines which cross each other where I've clicked. So far I've written those:

```
 #fr{
  float: right;
  margin-top: 5%;
  height: 720px;
  width: 1280px;
  position: relative;
  background-image: url(blueboard.jpg);
  border: 1px solid black; 
  clear:none;

}
canvas{
  border:1px solid red;
  float: right;
  height: 720px;
  width: 1280px;
  clear:none;
}//css part, I actually place the canvas on top of my div

//and on html...
  <canvas id="line"></canvas>

//js
function saveOO(e){
    var xo, yo;
    xo=e.clientX;
    yo=e.clientY; 
    ...

    document.getElementById("saved").innerHTML="The (0;0) = " +"("+xo+";"+yo+")";
    document.getElementById("ball").style.left=xo+'px';
    document.getElementById("ball").style.top=yo+'px';
    xylines(xo, yo);  
    ...;
  }
function lines(xo, yo){
   var xo, yo, xl, xline, yl, yline, Dx, Dy, a, b, c, d, e;
   xo=xo;
   yo=yo;
   a=$("#fr").position();
   b=$("#fr").width();
   c=$("#fr").height();
   Dy=a.top+100;
   Dx=a.left;
   d=Dx+b;
   e=Dy+c; 

   xline = document.getElementById("line");
   xl=xline.getContext("2d");
   xl.beginPath();
   xl.moveTo(Dx,yo);
   xl.lineTo(d,yo);
   xl.lineWidth = 15;
   xl.stroke();

   yline = document.getElementById("line");
   yl=yline.getContext("2d");
   yl.beginPath();
   yl.moveTo(xo,Dy);
   yl.lineTo(xo,e);
   yl.lineWidth = 15;
   yl.stroke();}
```

I have, as well, checked whether all variables assign a value and everything is good with that. The crossing point should be exactly where the blue ball is, it also positions on the place where it's clicked. As you can see on the image no lines show, even if I remove the blue background. Please, help me, maybe something is missing. I'm looking forward to your answers.
:)[image]

P.S. Dy is Y of the top left corner, Dx respectively X of the top left corner

Comment: Can you also show the element `#fr` and the way you call the function?

Comment: Please separate CSS and HTML from JS code

Comment: @Harry, I've updated the main post :)

Comment: @hindmost, is that what you intended I to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update 2**

A slightly amended fiddle where the lines span the entire width/height of the canvas:
https://jsfiddle.net/0y37qwvw/5/

This is by using `0` as the starting point for each and `canvas.width`/`canvas.height` as the ending point.

**Update**

Here is a fiddle demonstrating the use of a canvas overlay and responding to a click events.

https://jsfiddle.net/0y37qwvw/4/

The important thing is to get the relative x and y co-ordinates right, which I have done using event.offsetX and event.offsetY and a fallback for when they are not implemented:

```
document.getElementById("canvas-overlay").addEventListener("click", function( event ) {
    var x, y, clientRect;
    clientRect = event.target.getBoundingClientRect();
    x = (typeof event.offsetX !== 'undefined' ? event.offsetX : (event.clientX - clientRect.left));
    y = (typeof event.offsetY !== 'undefined' ? event.offsetY : (event.clientY - clientRect.top));

    lines(x, y, 50, 50);
}, false);
```

**Original answer**

Your code is incomplete, so it is hard to be sure what the exact problems are.

One problem though is that you have not directly set the width and height of the canvas element, which will result in the canvas being scaled.

You can do this on the canvas element:

```
<canvas id="line" height="720" width="1280"></canvas>
```

Demonstrated at:
https://jsfiddle.net/0y37qwvw/1/

You could also set the width and height programmatically:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("line");
canvas.width = 1280;
canvas.height = 720;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0y37qwvw/3/

Compare to what happens if the width and height are only set by CSS:

https://jsfiddle.net/0aph7yno/

If you still can't get it to work, set up a plunker/fiddle with the broken code.

Comment: hah, you just don't know how funny the result is :D :D :D. Actually now I can observe some progress in terms of that lines show! However, though, if I click on one place they show 5-6 cm to the right, take a look at the following picture. 
[IMG]http://i59.tinypic.com/e847pk.png[/IMG]

something is wrong with the positioning now, the ball has the so called `position: fixed` type of positioning, fr is `position: relative`

Comment: I'm still not sure what your exact code is so I've written my own example with a canvas overlay and added it to my answer.

Comment: two.5 questions. 
1. Is this a separate function?
2. Is the lines(x, y, 50, 50) function calling the drawing one and what 50, 50 appear to be?

Comment: 1. Have a look at the code in the fiddle; I rewrote some of your code. I think it should be clear but if not let me know which part. 2. 50, 50 is the length of the the horizontal and vertical lines drawn (since I wasn't sure what you intended). If you intended it to be across the whole canvas it can be easily changed; let me know if you're stuck.

Comment: it's simular, thanks a lot for the help, attention and etc. Sadly, I still can't fix this disposition, it's applying false coordinates, or I don't know. I think I've to continue debugging. Unfortunately xo and yo lines() receives exactly the same coordinates like the "ball" but the ball positions properly unlike the lines but at least they now appear, that's the good news. Thanks once again... :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code I have written, I tried to use as much as OOP style so it's easier to expand it. But still simple and clear.

http://jsfiddle.net/eeqhc2tn/2/

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('can');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var drawThese = [];

canvas.width = 500;
canvas.height = 500;
render();

//Line Code
function Line(sx, sy, ex, ey) {
    this.sx = sx;
    this.sy = sy;
    this.ex = ex;
    this.ey = ey;
}

Line.prototype.draw = function () {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(this.sx, this.sy);
    ctx.lineTo(this.ex, this.ey);
    ctx.stroke();
};

Line.drawCrossLines = function (x, y) {
    var horizontal = new Line(0, y, canvas.width, y);
    var vertical = new Line(x, 0, x, canvas.height);
    drawThese.push(horizontal);
    drawThese.push(vertical);
}

canvas.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    Line.drawCrossLines(e.offsetX, e.offsetY);
});


//Circle code
function Circle(x, y, r) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.r = r;
}
Circle.prototype.draw = function () {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.r, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.fill();
};

//Moving Circle Code that extends Circle
function MovingCircle() {
    Circle.call(this,0,0,10);
}

MovingCircle.prototype = Object.create(Circle.prototype);
MovingCircle.prototype.constructor = MovingCircle;

MovingCircle.prototype.move = function (x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

var pointer = new MovingCircle();
drawThese.push(pointer);
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove',function(e){
    pointer.move(e.offsetX, e.offsetY);
});

//Rendering and animation code
function render() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    drawThese.forEach(function (e) {
        e.draw();
    });
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found a working solution on my own, of course inspired by rpn. If you would like to make same or similar thing to what I this topic is about, a system including a container, canvas and a mouse event (click, in this case) you will have to follow this steps.

  1. You cannot draw directly to a div, you've to create something like an invisible overlay for canvas and to place it perfectly over the div.

  2. An important part is getting the proper coordinates, take into account that there are some tad but important differences between the various coords get methods. (`clientX/Y`, `offsetX/Y` and so on). It matters a lot.

  3. Last but not at least, you should carefully consider how you get container's dimensions, as you'll need them later. Remember! We are in a container, a.k.a. working with an area which is just part of the whole window (your browser).

At first I was receiving my coordinates with `clientX/Y` but maybe due to some mismatches between the get method for coordinates and the one for div's dimensions I was hammered by bugs. To solve this, I've created a method from which I take mouse click coordinates with `offsetX/Y`. This way you have to think of you container as if it is a separate coordinate system, different from your window's(which by default is general). This means that now the top left corner of this div has x:y = (0;0);

```
function getcooords(){
  xo = e.offsetX;
  yo = e.offsetY;   
  DrawLines(x0, y0); //invoke func DrawLines
}
```

Now we go to the moment where we should draw our lines.

```
 function DrawLines(x0,y0){ 
   //your variables here...
   w=$("#yourcontainer").width();
   h=$("#yourcontainer").height();
   Dy=0;
   Dx=0;
 }
```

That's the second step, Dx and Dy are the top and left properties of the div. Hence, from the what I've just said above, they will be equal to 0, both. Width and height of the container I take simply with jq but you can do it on another preferred way.

Generally speaking, that's the core of your drawing algorithm after we've taken needed dimensions and coordinates:

```
  xl.beginPath();
  xl.moveTo(b,yo);//start point of line
  xl.lineTo(Dx,yo);//end point of line
  xl.stroke(); //DRAW IT :)
```

Now, I've forgot to tell you that you have to define your lines at first, where should they be, what properties, styles should they have, etc..:

```
  var xline = document.getElementById("line");
  xl=xline.getContext("2d");
```

Remember! If you would like to delete, to erase the what you've drawn you'd have to define your lines FIRST and delete them after their definition. I'm saying definition, not drawing and you can draw the next 1, 2, 3... n lines and delete them over and over again if you follow this principle.

That's it guys, I hope I've explained it well, sorry for my English, probably I've made some tad mistakes but I hope you understand me. If you have any questions, please feel free to ask me, I'll try to do my best in order to help you.

:)